# How to break an axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I have generated a plot as below.

[image: plot]

The plot does not show the distribution as all data points are restricted to 10% of it. I tried log transformation, scale_y_continuous and scale_y_break, but none helped. I think I did not use them properly.

What I want is: Break the y axis from 400-2800 out of the plot. So I can see the distribution

Here is the original I code used:

```
ggplot(dat_o, aes_string(x="Treatment",y="FGF_21", fill="Treatment"))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.25, outlier.color = "red") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.25, size = 2 )+
  facet_wrap(~Mode)+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("TAC+vehicle","TAC+relaxin")) )+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons )+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20))+
  geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[1]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)+
  geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[2]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)
```

Code for log10 transformation

```
#log transformation
ggplot(dat_o, aes_string(x="Treatment",y="FGF_21", fill="Treatment"))+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.25, outlier.color = "red") +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.25, size = 2 )+
    scale_y_log10()+
    facet_wrap(~Mode)+
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("TAC+vehicle","TAC+relaxin")) )+
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons )+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20))+
    geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[1]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)+
    geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[2]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)
```

Code for scale_y_continuous

```
#scale_y_continuous
ggplot(dat_o, aes_string(x="Treatment",y="FGF_21", fill="Treatment"))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.25, outlier.color = "red") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.25, size = 2 )+
  facet_wrap(~Mode)+
  scale_y_continuous(c(400,2800), limits = c(0, 3000))+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("TAC+vehicle","TAC+relaxin")) )+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons )+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20))+
  geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[1]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)+
  geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[2]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)
```

[image: Result plot]

Code for scale_y_break

```
#scale_y_break
ggplot(dat_o, aes_string(x="Treatment",y="FGF_21", fill="Treatment"))+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.25, outlier.color = "red") +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.25, size = 2 )+
    facet_wrap(~Mode)+
    scale_y_break(c(400,2800), scales="fixed")+
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("TAC+vehicle","TAC+relaxin")) )+
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons )+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20))+
    geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[1]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)+
    geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept=paste('dat_bound$FGF_21[2]')), linetype="dashed", color="red", size=0.5)
```

The data is as follows

```
> dput(dat_o[1:30,c(1,12)])
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SHAM+vehicle", "TAC+vehicle", 
"TAC+relaxin", "TAC+Enalapril"), class = "factor"), FGF_21 = c(136.07, 
233.66, 63.28, 99.6, 190.43, 54.54, 141.27, 104.86, 136.07, 131.03, 
155.04, 75.54, 130.17, 191.02, 264.49, 97.75, 216.12, 204.42, 
431.37, 62.15, 90.38, 47.5, 74.84, 144.45, 88.4, 181.26, 232.14, 
128.01, 129.74, 771.73)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001fde1e21ef0>)
> dput(dat_bound[,9])
structure(list(FGF_21 = c(2865, 5.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think any of your data points are outside the range 0-500, so adjusting the scale limits might seem more sensible than to make a discontinuous axis (which ggplot2 discourages by design). At any rate, it's hard to help without any data to reproduce the plots with; would you might sharing (dummy) data that works with your code?

Comment: I need the hline that was drawn at ~2900 to be on the plot. That is the main reason I can't use a limit like 0-500. As per the recommendation I have added my data as an edit. Thank you for your time.

Comment: OP, when you define limits in any of the `scale_*` functions, you need to specify a *vector of two numbers*.  Specifying `c(400-2800)` does not specify a range, but becomes evaluated as `400` minus `2800`, or `-2400`.  If you want to have the axis limits 400-2800, the proper syntax is `c(400, 2800)`.  You will also need to specify that this should be applied to the `limits=` argument.  So in the example with `scale_y_continuous()`, you need to write as: `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(400, 2800))`.  This follows for all other places you define those limits.

Comment: Thank you @chemdork123, I corrected the syntax errors. But the output is the same. I am still debating it `scale_y_continuous` is the correct function to do this because it only produces a subplot, it never remove the unwanted region of the plot

Comment: The `scale_y_continuous(..)` function should adjust your y axis scale.  Are you assigning `limits = c(400, 2800)` inside that?  In the example code you posted, the vector is just sitting inside the parentheses and not assigned to `limits=`, which will not work.  The vector must be applied to the `limits=` argument or you will not see any effect.  take your plot (`p`) and try:  `p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(400, 2800))`.

Comment: I have edited the code and have added the sample output I get. Thanks